# Joining the tables while manipulating SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and am wondering how to join two tables based on the user ID while, at the same time, manipulating one of the columns. I have the table of orders per ID, and another table with ID demographics. I want to sum the orders per ID, and then join the demographics information.

Separately, the codes work:
This one sums the orders per id up:

```
SELECT SUM(order) AS expenses, id
FROM orders
GROUP BY id;
```

And this one joins another table:

```
SELECT orders.id, demographics.*
FROM orders
JOIN demographics
ON orders.id = demographics.user;
```

But how can you do the two simultaneously? So the table becomes like:

id | expenses | demographics.1 | demographics.2 | demographics.3 | etc

Comment: You don't do that, you return separate rows for each joined result, because what will you do if there are 100 or 1000? 1000 columns??

Comment: Indeed, demographics.* seems to not work in this case... Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Not clear what you want, and why you thought that would work. In SQL you join tables together, and aggregate that if necessary. Do you want rows or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT orders.id, sum(order) as expenses, max(demographics.1), max(demographics.2),...
FROM orders
JOIN demographics
ON orders.id = demographics.user
Group by orders.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    o.id,
    d.demographics.1,
    d.demographics.2,
    d.demographics.3,
    sum (o.order) Expenses
from order o,
    demographics d
where 1=1
    and.o.id = d.user
group by
    o.id
```